# Does this theorem concerning upper and lower bnound of a monotone decreasing function have a formal name?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation

This is the theorem:

Let $g$ be a monotone decreasing function and let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the following holds true:

$$\int_{a}^{b+1}g(x)dx \overset{(i)}{\leq} \sum\limits_{i=a}^{b}g(i)\overset{(ii)}{\leq}\int_{a-1}^{b}g(x)dx.$$

I am using this theorem in my bachelor thesis, which I have found on a webblog[1].

Does this theorem have a formal name or can you reference a book, where this is cited and proved for the obvious two reasons: I want to make sure, that this is true and furthermore I need to cite any theorem I use anyways in my thesis.

EDIT:
I also found this article on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence.
For the lower bound, we get exaclty the above mentioned theorem. Unfortunately, the upper bound is infinity.

[1] http://www.uni-protokolle.de/foren/viewt/227022,0.html

Comment: Can you please add a link to the blog?

Comment: Something of this kind is used in connection with the integral test for convergence of a monotone series.  Viewed as estimates of the integrals (rather than of the series), these are simply upper and lower Riemann sums for a monotone integrand.

Comment: The blog is in German unfortunately, but I add it anyways.

Comment: I may be missing something, but it seems to me a very easy exercise that everybody does when studying the Riemann integral for the first time. For sure there exists a textbook in the world where it is proved, but I suspect that you can prove it by yourself.